# What to choose: Community Builder Page or Visualforce?

Tags: lightning-community, community-builder, self-registration

I need to create a self-registration process for a community based on the Customer Service template. The problem is that Default Page and Configurable Self Reg Page do not meet our needs mostly because of styling. We also want to verify email address before creating a user in the system. Thus the two options left: Community Builder Page and Visualforce Page.

The official documentation seems to cover only Visualforce - [Customize Login Pages in Apex for Full Control](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_custom_login_page_about.htm). Yet I haven't found anything on customizing Community Builder Page and its lightning components `selfRegister` and its apex controller `LightningSelfRegisterController` except [Customize Code for Lightning Components on Login Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_custom_login_self_reg_lightning.htm&type=5).

So which option is better? Should I even consider using visualforce given that it's 2019 and lightning is the future of the platform?

Comment: I don't see anything about the self-registration use case that would require using Visualforce.  Personal opinion: any developer who isn't retiring in the next few years should focus on doing things the Lightning way wherever possible. You'll learn more and like what you build better.  `LightningSelfRegisterController` is not that complicated (at least no more complicated than the equivalent Visualforce controller).  Try it!

Comment: Yes, I am also 100% for the Lightning way. But some features, like [Identity Verification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_passwordless_custom_verification.htm), seem to be possible to customize only with Visualforce. And that's really annoying.